# What is causing this render artifact?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> in this .blend:

[image]

You may see the ground plane has two colors separated by a line:

[image: KO]

Using the same Blender version 2.76b, but on a different computer, or using CPU instead of GPU, this line will not be present: the ground is one solid color.
Also subdividing the plane or scaling it down will make the artifact disappear.

[image: OK]

[Our](http://blenderclan.tuxfamily.org/html/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=45262) question is, what is causing this, is it a bug in Blender or a problem in the .blend?

Comment: On my system, I see the anomaly using the CPU compute.  The line is not visible with GPU render (F12 or preview).  Very strange.

Comment: Would you mind using [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) instead of Pasteall?  Pasteall doesn't hold files for very long.

Comment: Very strange indeed. On my system the line shows when rendering on CPU only... I suspect it's a bug

Comment: I may guess it may be something related with the scale of the scene: there is big plane and  the "COUVERCKE HAUT" object it's being subdivided many times making its faces very tiny (eg. if you lower the value to 3 the issue disappears). Even though it's out of camera, it still contributes to the render. Anyway I can't imagine why this problem doesn't address GPU too.

Comment: @PGmath alright, I've moved the blend file to blend-exchange

Comment: It's definitely a bug, pls report it. CPU and GPU must not differ. GPU renders fine, the artifact is present with CPU render. When the ground plane is subdivided the artifact is gone.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in 2.77, and it only gets better (but not completely solved) by turning MOTION BLUR off. I believe this is still a BUG.  :-(